# batch file on network share closes right away after 'Run as administrator' is selected

Tags: windows, batch-file

Synopsis: create a .bat file on a network share, simply put `pause` in it, then save. Right-click new file & 'Run as administrator' it closes right away, **why?**

Moving the file to the local PC (%SYSTEMDRIVE%) it will work correctly. So its clearly an issue with the UNC path? How can I fix? I tried putting `pushd "%~dp0"` as the first-line, but same instant close issue. If your wondering what I am trying to do, here a snippet:

```
echo ------MADE BY ME-----
REM install from batch file location, a network UNC path
msiexec /i "%~dp0AppNameHere.msi" /qn /norestart /log %TEMP%\AppNameHere.log
echo Instructions > %PUBLIC%\Desktop\HowToUseApp.txt
```

If I double-click batch it fails with access denied. Right-clicking batch file & 'Run as administrator' causes it to open & close quickly. If I open cmd as admin, then run batch it works fine. I am confused as to the cause. If I create a new batch file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When UAC is enabled, elevated processes don't have access to network shares.  This is [by design](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx).

Note that the workaround in the linked article for the `EnableLinkedConnections` registry change [has unknown security consequences](https://serverfault.com/questions/182758/what-does-registry-setting-enablelinkedconnections-do-on-a-technical-level).  Historically, [even MS said you should avoid it](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/25cb7824-2a8d-4dbd-b802-1c64bed3a5e0/when-uac-is-enabled-what-vulnerabilities-does-the-enablelinkedconnections-registry-edit-cause?forum=w7itprosecurity), although the same KB article today is [much more benign](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/937624).

So, `cmd.exe` starts in an elevated process, tries to access the network drive so it can read the batch file, can't find the drive because it's not mapped for LocalSystem\Administrator, and exits.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742992/cannot-access-network-drive-in-powershell-running-as-administrator) another question with some more possible work-arounds for you.

Comment: Is it possible to catch this error? I mean, when i start the batch as admin from a network share, the opened cmd windows shall not close directly, but give an error message to the user.

Comment: @Strubbl No, not really possible to catch since the file is inaccessible. You have to write the whole script to account for it. I have written Powershell scripts that check to see if they're running in an elevated process. If not, they copy themselves to the temp folder and then execute themselves in a new elevated process. You could theoretically do the same with a batch file, but you're much more limited. You'd have to check if the file were running from the temp folder instead of testing for elevation.