# Creating Subdirectory With Date As Today(mm-dd-yyyy) in Network Drive

Tags: powershell

I am having a hard time making a subdirectory nested inside a current directory in a shared network drive.
I can create the folder

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Windows\system32> new-item

cmdlet New-Item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]: C:\Temp\Powershell\Date
Path[1]:
Type: directory


    Directory: C:\Temp\Powershell


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        06/18/2019  10:31 AM            Date


PS C:\Windows\system32> new-item

cmdlet New-Item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]: U:\gebersole\Documents\New Placements\UI
Path[1]:
New-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'U' does not exist.
At line:1 char:9
+ new-item <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (U:String) [New-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Are you running the session as Administrator? Sounds similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742992/cannot-access-network-drive-in-powershell-running-as-administrator/4777229)

Comment: Could be [UAC related](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3035277/mapped-drives-are-not-available-from-an-elevated-prompt-when-uac-is-co)

Comment: I am running it as administrator and no luck...

Comment: It looks like that PowerShell session is unable to see your "U:\" drive. An easy way to check is to cd to that drive. If that does not work you can type in `net use` it should list the available drives.

Comment: I solved this by using \\ for every leg of the path. The reason why it was not working when i was testing the path was because it was ending at New                      PS U:\> Test-Path U:\gebersole\Documents\'New Placements'\CDENTAL
True
PS U:\> new-item

Answer (score 2):

By default network drives are not available in an elevated process. You can find more information here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3035277/mapped-drives-are-not-available-from-an-elevated-prompt-when-uac-is-co

I would recommend Workaround Method 2. Run `net use` or `New-PsDrive` on the network drive, or run the script without elevation.

Comment: So strange but its not finding that drive Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unavailable  L:        \\10.0.0.6\qsoft          Microsoft Windows Network
Unavailable  Q:        \\nllxqlaw\lxqlaw         Microsoft Windows Network
Unavailable  R:        \\nlfps01\legal           Microsoft Windows Network
Unavailable  S:        \\nlfps01\public          Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> cd "U:\"
Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'U' does not exist.
At line:1 char:3
+ cd <<<<  "U:\"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (U:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

PS C:\Windows\system32> cd U:\
Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'U' does not exist.
At line:1 char:3

Comment: It's not strange; it's by design. If you configure the `EnableLinkedConnections` registry value, you can see mapped drives no matter whether you're elevated or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with trying to use a mapped drive and now only use the UNC format for the file paths.

Instead of using `U:\gebersole\Documents\New Placements\UI`, it might work to use the UNC format `\\host-name\share-name\file_path`, which in your case would be something like `\\gebersole\Documents\New_Placements`.

https://www.lifewire.com/unc-universal-naming-convention-818230

Comment: so the host name is actually \\nlfps01 and the path is gebersole\Documents\New Placements\UI i found the drive on the admin comp but even when i try to cd on the admin it wont find the drive this is really annoying.

Comment: When I use net use it gives me but nlfps01\it is not the directory where the subdirectory I want to create is in.. STUMPED  Status       Local     Remote                    Network



OK           Q:        \\nllxqlaw\lxqlaw         Microsoft Windows Network
OK           R:        \\nlfps01\legal           Microsoft Windows Network
OK           S:        \\nlfps01\public          Microsoft Windows Network
OK           T:        \\server2\timeclock       Microsoft Windows Network
OK           U:        \\nlfps01\it              Microsoft Windows Network

Comment: @AJG if you run PowerShell on your normal user account, are you able to access the drive? Like if you did `Test-Path \\nlfps01\your\path\here` on normal PowerShell (no admin) does it work? I had similar issues with Admin not seeing network drives and it is because running as admin does not transfer any permissions from your normal account.

Comment: Not from my account but i have access to the account where the drive was created and that one does but it is mapping to a folder thats not correct. I need it to map to \\nlfps01\gebersole but its mapping to \\nlfps01\it ....